# Is there any quick way to check if all of my plugins will work when upgrading Firefox?

Tags: plugins, updates, firefox

I depend on firefox plugins for my work, so updating is always a bit treacherous. But I also need to be using the latest browsers, so it's a necessary evil.

Is there any good way to check if all of my plugins will migrate well, ideally without manually going through all them one by one, and then I can migrate the moment they all become available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/is-it-compatible/) does what you ask.  But in a strange twist of irony it is only compatible with firefox 4.  Might be worth having a look though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable. This basically installs all of firefox in to a single folder (doesn't have to be a usb drive) along with all the user data and settings, that way you know that if you play around with the add-ons to get them working you won't affect your main browser.